# Can I Change the Behavior of MSMQ Message Error Handling by a Workflow Service?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I have a Workflow Service that has a few receives that listen to MSMQ queues. I would like to implement the following behavior:

1. If a correlation exception occurs (ie - workflow instance is gone), throw away the message.
2. If an InstanceLockException occurs (ie - this workflow instance is doing something on another server), put the message in the retry queue.

I have tried putting TransactedReceiveScope around the Receive activities, but it will put the message in the retry queue on a correlation error. Plus, it causes a lot of problems under heavy load.

Without the TransactedReceiveScope, the message is thrown away if there is an InstanceLockException.

Is there a way to implement this behavior (maybe via behavior extensions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [IErrorHandler for WCF](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/implementing-ierrorhandler.aspx) to catch all unhandled exceptions whether thrown by your app or by WCF. The thing you have to be careful about with the netMsmqBinding is that throwing a fault in this handler means the message has been "successfully" processed and it will taken off the queue. In your case when InstanceLockException occurs, you'll have to let it remain unhandled if you want the built-in MSMQ 4 retry handling to occur. You'll also need to allow the PoisonMessageException to remain unhandled for proper MSMQ retrying to occur.

Comment: This does not work for me. I tried returning True for HandleException, but the message always gets placed in the retry queue. I think that this error handling has to be caught earlier in the pipeline.

Comment: This is the only point WCF will let you work with exceptions, there are no other extension points. To signal to MSMQ that a message was "successfully" processed when an exception occurs that you **don't** want to retry, you need to provide a FaultException in the aptly named ProvideFault method. The MSMQ interaction with WCF won't let you "throw away" the exception. BTW: all returning true for HandleError method does is tell WCF this is the last IErrorHandler to invoke, it has no effect on the actual exception that was trapped. Typically, HandleError is only useful for exception logging.

Comment: I have implemented the ProvideFault method, and set the 'ref Message fault' by creating a new FaultException, faultException.CreateMessageFault(), fault = Message.CreateMessage. However, the failed messages still go into the retry queue. Is there a special type of FaultException I need to create? Are there any fields I need to set?

Comment: It seems like the error handler isn't being triggered by WCF. The standard FaultException will do for creating the soap fault that you need. To troubleshoot, add code in the HandleError to write the exception to a log file. Also, ensure that you **do not** create a fault for any exception of the PoisonMessageException type because that will interfere with the MSMQ/WCF interaction. Run the service to create the exceptions you're testing and make sure it is written to the log file. Also, may want to enable journaling in the MSMQ queue the service is using to know what is being processed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I decided to not deal with any error handling, and let the messages retry until it goes into the dead-letter queue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using Workflow, but knowing how MSMQ and WCF work you could try this

When a CorrelationException occurs:

- Catch the exception
- Return from your service method

Since your service method doesn't throw an exception it will think the message was successfully processed and remove it from the queue.

When a InstanceLockException occurs:

- Catch the exception
- rethrow the exception

Since your service method throws and exception it will think the message was not successfully processed and move it to the retry queue.

Comment: Yes, however, all these exceptions occur inside the WCF pipeline, so don't have the opporunity to catch and handle these exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to create a WCF custom behavior to catch those exceptions.